# Loop for interpret the python script (.py)

Tags: unix, python-2.7

I'm a beginner for Python. My question might be basic, but I cannot figure it out. What I want to do is to run the following command 100 times in which the variable "num" runs from 0 through 99.

python test.py input_num.txt -i 5 --cor_file=output_num.txt

For example:

python test.py input_0.txt -i 5 --cor_file=output_0.txt

python test.py input_1.txt -i 5 --cor_file=output_1.txt

...
   :::

python test.py input_99.txt -i 5 --cor_file=output_99.txt

I know that I have to write a script for running the loop, but cannot figure it out yet. If you have any recommendation, that would be very nice.

I tried to write a script called main.py containing the following commands, but it didn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import test
ext_str = '.txt'
inp = 'input_'
out = 'output_'

for num in range(0,99):    
  inp += 'num'
  inp_str = inp + ext_str

  out += 'num'
  out_str = out + ext_str

  python test.py inp_str -i 5 --cor_file=out_str
```

Thank you very much.

Best,
Pim

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to call the python interpreter on various files, e.g. you need to call the "python" shell command, it means that you have to create a shell script (and not a python script, actually you could do it with some python code but it would be way too complicated in your case):

```
for i in {0..99}
do
    python test.py input_$i.txt -i 5 --cor_file=output_$i.txt
done
```

put the above code in a ".sh" file then don't forget to "chmod +x the ", then run it with ./.sh (given that your are in the current directory).

N.B.: If you need some references on bash scripting : [Linux Shell Scripting Tutorial](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/)

Comment: Could you accept the answer if this has been helpful, thanks :)